# inserting id into table with random number

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I need to write a view that does a merge insert/update.
When inserting, I need to insert `id`.
This `id` is also being inserted by random number generator in another program ( which I can't change ).

I wanted to do `max(id) + 1`, but not sure if that is a good idea. Could you suggest any better solutions for this problem?

or

How about using with id as ( dbms_random .... ) do a

```
select * from table where id = ?
```

if row is not found, I will insert this id otherwise, I will generate another random and do a select.

Comment: your bigger issues will be in the other system that could generate a random number that would collide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this is for a Primary Key - then how about generating negative numbers for your part of the app (using a sequence) and leaving the random number wizardry in the positives...

Answer (score 0):

You can use rand() function for your request with random number !

Enjoy,

remontees